# Trigger Syntax Error 1064, Using IF/THEN and Dates

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Being a complete newbie to this, I thought I might be able to save my self a lot of headache by just asking for help...

When I try to run this I'm getting an Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL Syntax...

> CREATE TRIGGER payroll_lock BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR
>   UPDATE ON timesheet_entry FOR EACH ROW IF entry_date < '2013-07-25'
>   THEN raise_application_error(-20001, 'Cannot modify old records.');

I would also consider other options for stopping the insert/update/delete if the record is before a given fixed date.

Thanks for any help in fixing this! And explanations are appreciated, I don't know much in this particular area.

Answer (score 0):

you should `CALL` keyword before `raise_application_error` function.
another tip is you should use `NEW` or `OLD` keyword for update trigger.

I'm not sure but I don't think you can create multiple trigger at same command with OR(this is first time I see that).

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER payroll_lock BEFORE UPDATE  ON wp_links
   FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
      IF NEW.entry_date < '2013-07-25' THEN
         CALL raise_application_error(-20001, 'Cannot modify old records.');
      END IF;
      END//
```